# Rolling back edit should undo community

Tags: feature-request, edits, community-wiki, rollbacks

I edited [one of my answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19108008/what-are-the-java-semantics-of-an-escaped-number-in-a-character-literal-e-g) for the tenth time and it turned into a community wiki.

This was a surprise - I was unaware that just editing would have such an effect.

Having noticed the effect, I then rolled back the edit, but the conversion to community wiki remained. Again, a surprise.

A quick search here suggested that the conversion to wiki can't be undone. (Actually, this is not true. "Can't" is the wrong word... "won't" is correct: It has been *decided* to not allow such an update. If we can put a man on the moon using nothing but slide rules and chalk, we can surely update a row in a table somewhere.)

Can we have one or both of the following changes:

1. When editing for the 10th time, a pop-up warns that committing further changes will cause the post to convert to a community wiki
2. Rolling back *actually* rolls back - ie *all* effects of editing (in this case conversion to community wiki) are rolled back

Comment: (Want me to un-wikify it in the meantime?)

Comment: How does one use a slide rule and chalk to go to the moon?

Comment: I vote for getting rid of auto-wiki and replacing them with mod-flags instead.

Comment: @minitech yes please :)

Comment: @ColeJohnson oh, there was also rockets, space toilets and stuff, but the calculations were done "old school"

Answer (score 6):

The wikification of posts that have been excessively edited is there to prevent abuse, most notably to prevent users from trying to get extra views/votes for their posts by editing them over and over to bump them up on the "active" tab.

If rolling back an edit rolled back the CW status then users could just roll back an edit, then roll back the rollback, and so on to bump the post without CW-ing it.

From the point of view of the system a rollback is just like any other edit, except it just so happens to be editing the post to what it was at an earlier point in time.

Generally if you're hitting this it's a sign that you're editing your posts more than you should be.  You should probably be making fewer more significant edits rather than frequent smaller edits.

There are rare occasions in which posts just need that much editing, and for which the edits are not abusive or inappropriate.  In such cases you can flag the post for moderator attention and they can, if they feel it is appropriate, un-CW the post

Comment: If the aim is to prevent a user from editing their own questions or answers *"over and over to bump them up on the 'active' tab"*, then this is the wrong means to accomplish that. Can't we just address that problem directly? E.g., allow the edits (users should always be able to improve what is written), but just don't count more than *N* edits by the same user toward the 'active' tab (or whatever). IOW, what we have so far sounds like a primitive and indirect "solution".

Comment: @Drew The problem there is that if you stop bumping a post when it's edited then it would allow vandalism, other improper edits, dramatic changes in the content or its quality, etc. to go unnoticed.  There's a reason for the active tab, and it's because it's important for the community to see when a post is modified.

Comment: Again, it sounds like the wrong solution for the (new) problem you describe.  (But I am ignorant of any technical/implementation considerations.)  If the (new) problem is to not have such edits go unnoticed then log them or otherwise make them noticeable somewhere.  That need is independent of the current "solution", no?  What does that need have to do with transforming a user's question or answer into a community one?  I'm asking about a *logical* connection, not whether the *implementation* currently couples the two or needs to be the way it is.

Comment: @Drew There's no way to separate the two.  The edit needs to be made noticeable so that abusive edits can be fixed and further action taken, so that good edits can be rewarded, so that bad edits can be fixed, etc.  It is that same attention that often results in extra votes, which is the goal of the abuse we're trying to prevent.  It doesn't matter how the attention is given, if it's given it's feeding the abusive behavior.  Saying they should be decoupled and actually decoupling them is quite different.